# Can you take a mortgage on a property if the other properties of the same color have a house?

Tags: monopoly

In Monopoly, suppose you own the brown color group ("Old Kent Road" and "Whitechapel Road"). Now further suppose you have built a single house on either one of these two properties (eg Old Kent Road).

**Can you now take out a mortgage on the other (Whitechapel Road) one or do you have to sell the house (on Old Kent Road) first?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must sell the house(s) before you can mortgage the property. From the [rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf), page 4 (emphasis mine):

> MORTGAGES… Unimproved properties can be mortgaged through
>   the Bank at any time. Before an improved property can be mortgaged,
>   **all the buildings on all the properties of its color-group must be sold**
>   back to the Bank at half price.